# random.multivariate_normal on a dask array?

Tags: numpy, dask

I've been struggling to find a way to get this calc that works for a dask workflow.

I have code that uses np.random.mulivariate_normal function and while many of these types are available to us on dask array it seems this one it not. Sooo.... I attempted to create my own based on an example provided in the dask [documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-design.html).

Here is my attempt which is giving errors that I am having difficulty understanding.  I also provided random input variables to make it easy to replicate:

```
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

def mvn(mu, sigma, n, blocksize):
    chunks = ((blocksize,) * (n // blocksize),
              (blocksize,) * (n // blocksize))

    name = 'mvn'   # unique identifier

    dsk = {(name, i, j): (np.random.multivariate_normal(mu,sigma, blocksize))
                         if i == j else
                         (np.zeros, (blocksize, blocksize))
             for i in range(n // blocksize)
             for j in range(n // blocksize)}

    dtype = np.random.multivariate_normal(0).dtype  # take dtype default from numpy

    return da.Array(dsk, name, chunks, dtype)

n = 10000
A = da.random.normal(0, 1, size=(n,n), chunks=(1000, 1000))
sigma = da.dot(A,A.transpose())
mu = 4.0*da.ones(n, chunks = 1000)
R =  da.numpy.random.mvn(mu, sigma, n, chunks=(100))
```

Any suggestions or am I so far off the mark here that I should abandon all hope?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a cluster to run this on, you can use my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898793/can-i-create-a-multivariate-normal-matrix-using-dask/63903825#63903825), copied here for refrence:

An work arround for now, is to use a cholesky decomposition. Note that any covariance matrix C can be expressed as C=G*G'. It then follows that x = G'*y is correlated as specified in C if y is standard normal (see this [excellent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163470/generating-correlated-random-numbers-why-does-cholesky-decomposition-work) on StackExchange Mathematic). In code:

**Numpy**

```
n_dim =4
size = 100000
A = np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim)
covm = A.dot(A.T)

x=  np.random.multivariate_normal(size=size, mean=np.zeros(len(covm)),cov=covm)
## verify numpys covariance is correct
np.cov(x, rowvar=False)
covm
```

**Dask**

```
## create covariance matrix
A = da.random.standard_normal(size=(n_dim, n_dim),chunks=(2,2))
covm = A.dot(A.T)

## get cholesky decomp
L = da.linalg.cholesky(covm, lower=True)

## drawn standard normal 
sn= da.random.standard_normal(size=(size, n_dim),chunks=(100,100))

## correct for correlation
x =L.dot(sn.T)
x.shape

## verify
covm.compute()
da.cov(x, rowvar=True).compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer can be fleshed out, but I imagine you would have an easier time using dask's `delayed`, `da.from_delayed` and `da.*stack`.

One immediate problem I see with what you have: with `np.random.multivariate_normal(mu,sigma, blocksize)` you are directly calling the function, instead of making the spec. You probably wanted `(np.random.multivariate_normal, mu,sigma, blocksize)`. This shows that working with raw dask dictionaries can be tricky!