# Can I create a multivariate_normal matrix using dask?

Tags: python, pyspark, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

Somewhat related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337612/random-multivariate-normal-on-a-dask-array), I am trying to replicate `multivariate_normal` in `dask`:
Using numpy I can create a multivariate normal matrix with a specified covariance using:

```
import numpy as np
n_dim = 5
size = 300
A = np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim) # a matrix
covm = A.dot(A.T) # A*A^T is positive semi-definite, as a covariance matrix
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(size=300, mean=np.zeros(len(covm)),cov=covm) # generate data
```

I however need a significantly large matrix with `n_dim = 4_500_000` and `size = 100000`. This will be expensive to compute both with respective to CPU and memory. Fortunately, I have access to a Cloudera DataScience Workbench Cluster and was trying to solve this using `dask`:

```
import dask.array as da
n_dim = 4_500_000
size = 100000
A = da.random.standard_normal((n_dim, n_dim))  
covm = A.dot(A.T)
#x = da.random.multivariate_normal(size=300, mean=np.zeros(len(covm)),cov=covm) # generate data
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.random.normal), I cannot find any function that seem to do what I need it to. Does anyone know a solution / workarround, possibly using `xarray` or any other module that runs on clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An work arround for now, is to use a cholesky decomposition. Note that any covariance matrix C can be expressed as C=G*G'. It then follows that x = G'*y is correlated as specified in C if y is standard normal (see this [excellent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163470/generating-correlated-random-numbers-why-does-cholesky-decomposition-work) on StackExchange Mathematic). In code:

**Numpy**

```
n_dim =4
size = 100000
A = np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim)
covm = A.dot(A.T)

x=  np.random.multivariate_normal(size=size, mean=np.zeros(len(covm)),cov=covm)
## verify numpys covariance is correct
np.cov(x, rowvar=False)
covm
```

**Dask**

```
## create covariance matrix
A = da.random.standard_normal(size=(n_dim, n_dim),chunks=(2,2))
covm = A.dot(A.T)

## get cholesky decomp
L = da.linalg.cholesky(covm, lower=True)

## drawn standard normal 
sn= da.random.standard_normal(size=(size, n_dim),chunks=(100,100))

## correct for correlation
x =L.dot(sn.T)
x.shape

## verify
covm.compute()
da.cov(x, rowvar=True).compute()
```